# Недопонимание с Linux на примере демона.

Tags: linux, c, процесс, демон

Чтобы создать демона (по крайней мере в Linux), то нужно предпринять ряд событий, которые я сейчас опишу. В конце вопросы, если кто-то разбирается, то просьба овтетить, буду признателен.

1) Нужно вызвать функцию `fork()` для создания дочернего процесса и завершить родительский процесс. Это делается для того, чтобы наш дочерний процесс запутился в фоновом режиме (если не прав, то поправляйте)

```
if( (pid = fork()) < 0)
         return -1;
else if(pid)
         exit(0);
```

2) Затем мы вызываем функцию `setsid()`, которая создает новый сеанс. К тому же, вызывающий процесс становится ведущим в группе, ведущим процессом нового сеанса и не имеет контролирующего терминала.

```
if(setsid() < 0) 
        return -1;
```

В книге `"Разработка сетевых приложений" Стивенс У.Р`, откуда я и беру этот пример, автор вызывает еще один раз функцию `fork()`, для того, чтобы гарантировать, что демон не сможет автоматически получить управляющий терминал, когда будет открывать устройство терминала. Заметьте, что при завершении родительского процесса (в нашем случае `первого дочернего процесса`), посылается всем процессам в сеансе (в том числе и нашему `второму дочернему процессу`) сигнал `SIGHUP` (when someone kills the terminal, without killing app running inside of termiтal window, OS sends the signal to the program), который нам нужно игнорировать.

3) Производим смену текущего каталога командой `chdir("/");`

4) Закрываем дескрипторы файлов. Автор делает это таким образом

```
for(i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
        close(i);
```

И дальше больше... Остальной код приводить не буду, так как он не относится к сути вопросов, но в интеренете есть книга, которую я указал ранее, где вы можете найти пример полностью.

Собственно говоря, мои `вопросы`:

1) Вопрос может показаться глупым, но я не совсем понимаю, что означает `управляющий терминал`. Это что-то вроде терминала из под `root`? Объясните, пожалуйста, что это и что он делает.

2) Зачем нужно менять текущий каталог? В книге об этом сказано мало и мне не совсем понятно

3) За что отвечают дескрипторы, которые мы закрываем? И нужно ли их вообще закрывать?

Comment: Управляющий терминал это то окно консоли в котором вы запустили программу. Если он запускается из скрипта (например запуска системы), то управляющим терминалом в каком то роде будет он. И он не продолжит свое выполнение, пока не увидит, что вызванный процесс завершился. Если это реальный терминал, то он будет занят до завершения вашей программы. А так как родитель завершается, то терминал это видит и продолжает жить своей жизнью. Закрываемые дескрипторы - в первую очередь 3 основных STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR, остальное перестраховка. На счет смены каталога не знаю

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Вопрос может показаться глупым, но я не совсем понимаю, что означает управляющий терминал. Это что-то вроде терминала из под root? Объясните, пожалуйста, что это и что он делает.

Если кратко, то это терминал связанный с текущей консольным сеансом (*session*). Указан в частности в столбце `TTY` `ps`'а. По факту он эквивалентен одному из устройств `/dev/tty*` для «настоящей» консоли или /dev/pts* для псевдотерминалов (unix98). Также есть специальное устройство `/dev/tty`, ссылающееся на *управляющий терминал* ([*controlling terminal*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_03)) текущего процесса.

Основное назначение этой абстракции — переключение между группами процессов — только одна из которых может быть на переднем плане (foreground), а остальные в фоне (background). Также УТ (находясь в *каноническом режиме*) отвечает за посылку сигналов процессам находящимся на переднем плане при появлении на входе специальных символов (например `^C` или `^Z`) . Кроме того с помощью УТ программы могут запрашивать непосредственно у пользователя какие-то данные, например пароль, когда ввод/вывод перенаправлен, так в частности поступают `ssh` или `sudo`.

Вообще говоря, в UNIX управление заданиями, да и всей подсистемы связанной с терминалами, — довольно запутанная вещь со множеством мелких и крупных кочек, большинство из которых навеяно историей и необходимостью сделать всё гибко, но в то же время чисто, так что описание назначения и деталей УТ, а также таких абстракций, как «группа процессов», «сессия», «лидер сессии» итд, заслуживают отдельной главы в книге или хотя бы [статьи](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

> 2) Зачем нужно менять текущий каталог? В книге об этом сказано мало и мне не совсем понятно

В принципе это не обязательно, но является хорошей практикой освобождать неиспользуемые ресурсы. Например, если это не сделать, то нельзя будет отмонтировать ФС с каталогом откуда пользователь запустил демона.

> 3) За что отвечают дескрипторы, которые мы закрываем? И нужно ли их вообще закрывать?

То же что и предыдущее, не обязательно, но обычно является хорошей практикой. Первые три — это стандартные потоки ввода/вывода/ошибок, а остальные — другие дескрипторы, которые могут быть открыты — различные сокеты, файлы итп.

К сожалению, в POSIX нет простого и переносимого способа, который позволяет просто «закрыть все открытые дескрипторы» или хотя бы «запросить все открытые д.», поэтому обычной практикой является перебирать их все подряд, от нулевого до последнего и закрывать. Да, более переносимым вариантом, не полагающийся на магическую константу «64», будет:

```
for(int fd=0, maxfd=sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX); fd<maxfd; fd++) {
    close(fd);
}
```

В BSD-мире есть довольно удобный вызов [`closefrom ()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=closefrom&sektion=2), который закрывает все дескрипторы выше указанного. В некоторых системах есть аналогичный вызов `fcntl` — `F_CLOSEM`.

На Linux и некоторых других системах вместо этого можно посмотреть содержимое /proc/self/fd (или `/dev/fd/*`) и закрыть только действительно открытые.

Другие замечания по этому зоопарку расписаны [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899038/getting-the-highest-allocated-file-descriptor/918469#918469). Реальный пример поддержки различных систем с тоннами условной компиляции можно посмотреть, например, в [`openssh`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/openbsd-compat/bsd-closefrom.c).

Кроме того первые три дескриптора (stdin, stdout, stderr) стоит переоткрыть, например, на /dev/null, дабы избежать ошибок в дальнейшем.

### Другие замечания

Алгоритм «демонизации», опустив обработку ошибок и прочее, можно записать в 4 строчки. Причём непосредственно к демонизации относится только первая, и частично вторая, а остальные — лишь желательная подчистка.

```
if( fork() ) exit (0); // Собственно демонизация
setsid ();             // отвязка от управляющего терминала
if( fork() ) exit (0); // самозащита, чтобы случайно не подцепить новый УТ во время работы
cleanup_everything (); // различная очистка и освобождение всех не нужных ресурсов
```

Comment: *Кроме того первые три дескриптора (stdin, stdout, stderr) стоит переоткрыть, например, на /dev/null — это сделает.* — что сделает? (видимо, не дописано).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, подчистил, спасибо... адекватную мотивацию придумать не смог...

Comment: Про управляющий терминал я бы добавил, что это именно то устройство (часть ядра) при вводе на котором (при соответствующих настройках "stty") `^C`, `^\\` и т.п. ядро отправляет соответствующий сигнал группе процессов, для которых это управляющий терминал. (мда..., косноязычно как-то вышло (- )

Comment: @avp, не хотел сначала добавлять, дабы ответ не разрастался, но как-то всё прям органично вписалось...